# How to delete rows in html table by using a parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

How I can delete rows in HTML table by using a parameter.
In this example, I want to delete all the row that contains "Rock" in Data 1. "Rock" will be the parameter. I'm using mvc4.

```
<input type="text" id="tpcName" class="inputBox">

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 50px;"></th>
      <th style="width: 50px;">Data 1</th>
      <th style="width: 50px;">Data 2</th>
      <th style="width: 50px;">Data 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Rock</td>
      <td>Soil</td>
      <td>Sand</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Rain</td>
      <td>Water</td>
      <td>Sea</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Rock</td>
      <td>Soil</td>
      <td>Sand</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Rock</td>
      <td>Soil</td>
      <td>Sand</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(tpcName.value)"> Delete</button>
```

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: var table = document.getElementById('tableId');
        for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
                alert(table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML);
        }


I only tried showing the value of Data1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't describe what you have tried already. But for example:

```
const rows = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('TD'));
rows.forEach(rowItem => {
  if (rowItem.innerHTML === 'Rock') {
    rowItem.remove();
  }
})
```

Find all the table cell elements. Then loop through and delete the item if it contains your text in the innerHTML. Here is a pen: https://codepen.io/shnigi/pen/qBOQbvb

also note that the remove method isn't supported in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

in plain javascript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr => {
    if(tr.children[1].textContent ==="Rock"){
        tr.remove()
    }
});
```

first we query all of the  tags and loop over them to see if their first children have the text "Rock" if so delete the

### Suggestion 0

for the td that you want to check for a value, give it a class. This makes it easy to write clean and faster(though not noticeably) code.

like so

```html
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="first_col">Rock</td>
      <td>Soil</td>
      <td>Sand</td>
    </tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="first_col">Rock</td>
      <td>Soil</td>
      <td>Sand</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  </tbody>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#myTable >* .first_col').forEach(td => {
    if(td.textContent ==="Rock"){
        td.parentNode.remove()
    }
})
```

### Suggestion 1

To tune/change this, it's useful to learn how to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: domCollection is an array-like structure, so here you can not use `forEach`. You must invert the domCollection to array structure first.

Comment: @fengxh [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which has a [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) function

Comment: oh it's my fault, sorry

Comment: I forgot to include the table id. Sorry
Can you edit it so that the only table with the same id will be affected. Thanks

Comment: Can it be used in mvc4? I am having an error on it.

Comment: @ClementBranzuelaGRANE What have you tried? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I tried your suggestions. In my code it have errors in the greater than sign, open parenthesis in if condition then open curly bracket after the if condition.

Comment: I think it can only use on higher mvc 4 version. I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your rows inside tbody and check which rows have your specified content, filter out those rows then you can delete it from your dom or you can use some css to hide those rows.

```
function removeRow(param){
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr"))
  .filter(row => Array.from(row.children).filter(col => col.innerText == param).length !== 0)
  .forEach(row => document.querySelector("tbody").removeChild(row))
}
```

Note: If you remove the rows. They cannot be restored back. You will have to create new nodes. If your program needs to get them back then you must use CSS to hide your rows.